# Pearl and honey bubble tea problem

Tags: probability

> A bubble tea shop gives customers the options to add pearls or honey to their bubble teas. 63% of all customers add pearls to their bubble teas. 60% of those who add pearls to their bubble teas request for honey to be added. 75% of those who do not add pearls to their bubble teas do not request for honey to be added. One customer is selected at random.
>
> Draw a tree diagram to represent this information, showing all possible outcomes.

My tree diagram is as follows:

First branch:            Second branch has two branches

Add Pearl (0.63)   -   add honey (0.60)  and  did not add Honey (0.40)

Add Honey (0.1175)

Not adding Pearl & honey (0.3525)

Sorry as I did not know how to construct tree diagram here. Please advise if I am correct? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Out of a **grand total** of $\bf 100$:
$n(P)=63$ and $n(P\cap H)=0.6\times63=37.8$
So, $n(P\cap H')=25.2$
$n(P'\cap H')=0.75(100-63)=27.75$
So, $n(H\cap P')=0.25(100-63)=9.25$

**Venn Diagram:**
[image]

**Tree Diagram:**
[image]